# While extracting data from excel sheet using python (xlrd package). getting some junk data too

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm extracting data from excel sheet using python (xlrd package). With the original data im getting some junk data, please help me to remove those

Getting junk values like [text:u as below:

[text:u'NAME', text:u'JACK']

```
<CODE>

from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('C:/Users/arun/Desktop/EX.xls')
sheet0 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
#sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(1)

print sheet0.col(0) 
print sheet0.col(2)
print sheet0.col(3)
print sheet0.col(4)
print sheet0.col(5)
print sheet0.col(6)
print sheet0.col(7)
print sheet0.col(8)
print sheet0.col(9)
print sheet0.col(10)
print sheet0.col(12)
print sheet0.col(13)
print sheet0.col(14)
print sheet0.col(15)
print sheet0.col(16)
print sheet0.col(17)
print sheet0.col(18)
print sheet0.col(19)
print sheet0.col(20)
print sheet0.col(21)
print sheet0.col(22)
print sheet0.col(23)
print sheet0.col(24)
print sheet0.col(25)
print sheet0.col(26)
print sheet0.col(27)

</CODE>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your "junk" looks like a list of xlrd `Cell`s that are of type "text". That is, I don't think it is junk; it is a normal return value created by xlrd.  If you want the values from a column (say, column 0), try

```
print sheet0.col_values(0)
```

See https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#sheet.Sheet.col_values-method

Answer (score 1):

I found by using str(sheet0.col(0)) will drop the text:u output.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using sheet.cell(), I recommend to use sheet.cell_value to drop that extra (text:').